# How to edit/import node coordinates (mesh) in Abaqus with python script?

Tags: python, tuples, mesh, abaqus

I would like to ask for help to modify/edit the mesh of a Part Instance (under Assembly).

I have tried (code below), but it is not possible because of the tuple:

> mdb.models[modelName].rootAssembly.instances[instanceName].nodes[i].coordinates[0] = newCoordXYZ[0] # for x
>   mdb.models[modelName].rootAssembly.instances[instanceName].nodes[i].coordinates[1] = newCoordXYZ[1] # for y
>   mdb.models[modelName].rootAssembly.instances[instanceName].nodes[i].coordinates[2] = newCoordXYZ[2] # for z
>
> *TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment*

Or, if possible, to directly add/assign the mesh (which is already stored in a variable - newCoordXYZ) to the geometry in the Assembly module!?

Any idea/suggestion is more than welcomed!

PS: I know that the modification of the mesh can be easily done in the Part Module (mesh dependent) with the editNode() command.

> partName = mdb.models[modelName].parts[partName]
>   partName.editNode(nodes=partName.nodes,coordinates=newCoordXYZ)

**EDIT 01:**

**comment**

I'm not sure, I might make so trivial mistake.
I still obtain the following error: AttributeError: 'PartInstance' object has no attribute 'editNode', which is in agreement with the documentation:

The documentation says:

> Abaqus > Scripting Reference > Python commands > Assembly commands > Assembly object:

```
Access
import assembly
mdb.models[name].rootAssembly
```

> Abaqus > Scripting Reference > Python commands > Assembly commands > PartInstance object:

```
Access
import assembly
mdb.models[name].rootAssembly.allinstances
mdb.models[name].rootAssembly.instances[name]
```

and

> Abaqus > Scripting Reference > Python commands > Edit mesh commands > Assembly object: editNode(...)
>   This method changes the coordinates of the given nodes on a part instance.
>
> Abaqus > Scripting Reference > Python commands > Edit mesh commands > Part object
>   has no editNode(...) cmd

So, by using this cmd: mdb.models[name].rootAssembly.instances[name] I cannot use editNode()...

**py code**

```
################################## LIBRARY #############################
from datetime import date

from part import *
from material import *
from section import *
from assembly import *
from step import *
from interaction import *
from load import *
from mesh import *
from optimization import *
from job import *
from sketch import *
from visualization import *
from connectorBehavior import *
import regionToolset 

import assembly
import visualization
import os
import datetime
import shutil
from odbAccess import *
import time
import numpy
import numpy as np
import re
import meshEdit

############### Add textFileName with new coord (+ imp )######################
fileNameImp = open("out_newCoordX_Imp.txt","r")
impVect = fileNameImp.readlines() 

fileNameImp.close()

####################### Add modelName and instanceName #######################
modelName    = 'Model-1'
instanceName = 'Part-1-1'

assemblyInstance = mdb.models[modelName].rootAssembly.instances[instanceName]

newCoordXYZ = numpy.zeros((len(assemblyInstance.nodes),3))

for i in assemblyInstance.nodes:
        newCoordXYZ[i.label-1][0] = float(impVect[i.label-1])
        newCoordXYZ[i.label-1][1] = i.coordinates[1]
        newCoordXYZ[i.label-1][2] = i.coordinates[2]

assemblyInstance.editNode(nodes=assemblyInstance.nodes,coordinates=newCoordXYZ)
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way you do it for the part, you should do it for assembly instance:

```
assemblyInstance = mdb.models[modelName].rootAssembly.instances[instanceName]
assemblyInstance.editNode(nodes=assemblyInstance.nodes,coordinates=newCoordXYZ)
```

Make sure to make your instance independent!

Comment: Are you sure, because by using this cmd: `mdb.models[name].rootAssembly.instances[name]`, we create a PartInstance object for which the `editNode()` cmd cannot be used.
However, I edited my post and added the info from documentation + all py code.